# Using WPF how to use Binding to Grayscale an Image on some condition

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, converters

The application ia a messenger in which I am using microsoft lync client for this purpose. In one of the context I am getting the contacts (which is an object of LyncClient having properties like name, image , Availability, etc) in a listview and loading them in a data template which is defined as follow:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContactsTemplate">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="10">
            <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{Binding Availability, Converter={StaticResource AvailabilityToPresenceColor}}" Opacity="0.75">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="20" Margin="15,0,15,15"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

It has Grid container in which we have an image and textblock controls which show the image and name of the contact and as its shown below the background of stackpanel is binded to Availability property of lync **Contact** object with a converter which map the availibility status to a color so that for example the background of stackpanel will turn red when the contact availibility is busy.

I want to have similar effect for the image control as well.

I am new to binding so totaly lost in this bindig concept.

My idea was: there is a effect evend handler for image so i thought of using that for this purpose and use

and inside the converter under some condition I want to use some code in which i need to get the image source, but as we are getting the image source through binding

please suggest me your ideas.

---

Well as u can see in the code 
`<Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title} effect="{Binding Availability, Converter={StaticResource AvailabilityToPresenceColor}}"/>` 
I am just binding source of image control with  a  *property of **Contact** object*. I want to send the Availability properties of a Contact object to Convert method of IValueConverter or I want to bind the image with the whole **Contact** Object if it is possible...or if some other way please let me know.

#####################***comment attachment***

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    MemoreyStream ms=new MemoryStream(_image);
    bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.EndInit();
 var grayBitmapSource = new FormatConvertedBitmap();
    grayBitmapSource.BeginInit();
    grayBitmapSource.Source = ms;
    grayBitmapSource.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.Gray32Float;
    grayBitmapSource.EndInit();
.....
```

now the thing is i have grayBitmapSource which is of type FormatConvertedBitmap and i dont know how to convert it to Stream again.

Comment: you may want to have a look at the WPF Shader Effect Library, which contains a monochrome effect you could apply using some triggers http://wpffx.codeplex.com/

Comment: @HighCore
well thanx for your reply, but the question intention is not about to apply color effects or image processing...my question is much more relative to binding, i have an issue with binding.
please once again go through my question you'll be able to find out what m i asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking at this article about image processing in WPF: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/237226/Image-Processing-is-done-using-WPF

Using the image processing logic, you create the different pictures for each availability status. You could use an IValueConverter, but that means you have to reprocess the image each time the availability status changes. Instead, you can simply change your Contact class so that when you change the Availability property, it automatically signals WPF to get the picture referenced by the Image property:

```
public class Contact : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // EDIT: INotifyPropertyChanged implementation.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    // EDIT: INotifyPropertyChanged implementation.

    private ContactAvailability _Availability;

    public ContactAvailability Availability
    {
        get { return _Availability; }
        set
        {
            _Availability = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Availability");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Image");
        }
    }

    public BitmapImage _AvailablePicture;
    public BitmapImage _BusyPicture;

    public BitmapImage Image
    {
        get
        {
            switch (this.Availability)
            {
                case ContactAvailability.Available:
                    return this._AvailablePicture;
                case ContactAvailability.Busy:
                    return this._BusyPicture;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** (too long for comment):

I added the code to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. This is very common in WPF so I thought you were familiar with this approach already.

In your example, `Image.Source` is a `DepencyProperty`. When a class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you can tell WPF that one of its properties has changed. You simply raise the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event with the name of the property that changed. This signals WPF to update all `DepencyProperty`s that bind to the given property.

> how is this different with binding in term of image processing. I mean every time the availibility changes then in this way also the image processing code should be execute as well. am I right or not @bouvierr?

No. In this case, we would only execute the image processing a fixed number of times to create the picture for each availability status (2 times for each contact in my example). For example, we could create all pictures during application startup (3 contact x 2 status = 6 pictures) and store them in each contact's `_AvailablePicture` and `_BusyPicture` fields.

Here is the IMPORTANT part: when we SET the `Availability` property, we also call `NotifyPropertyChanged("Image")`. This will force WPF to update the `Image.Source` `DepencyProperty` because it binds to `Contact.Image`. This will return a different picture, because the `Availability` has changed.

In my example, I decided to store the pictures. This might not be the best solution for you. It consumes more memory, but saves processing time. If you prefer to re-process images each time the Availability status changes, you should change the `Contact.Image` property to something like:

```
    public BitmapImage Image
    {
        get
        {
            switch (this.Availability)
            {
                case ContactAvailability.Available:
                    return this._AvailablePicture;
                case ContactAvailability.Busy:
                    return GetImageWithColorFilter(this._AvailablePicture, Colors.Red);
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanx for your answer, but i have a question.
how is this different with binding in term of image processing. I mean every time the availibility changes then in this way also the image processing code should be execute as well. am I right or not @bouvierr? or are you trying to have multiple images for each availability status for same person contact?  if no the then how your switch is working ?
well I am totally new to C# and WPF so might be I am wrong that's way I couldn't figure out how INotifyPropertyChanged and this code will work?
I'll be happy if you elaborate how this logic will work.

Comment: thanx mate i wanted to upvote for your solution but as my account is new I need 15 reputation point for that so ill do it as i got those point ;).
**well** First solution is interesting as it save the processing time, out of my understanding we have to write the logic to create the  different images according to availability for each user, where the app loaded all contact,am I right bouvierr? If yes then how it will creat images for different availibilty when the user changes his account picture. I think some how it should be linked with NotifyPropertyChange for the image, right?

Comment: well in your second solution just for testing i write some piece of code for offline mode to make the image gray but face a problem as the Image is of type Stream and after conversion I have a FormatConvertedBitmap which I dont know how ..... to convert it back to Stream. I'll add the code as a next comment. 
*******************refer to next comment*******************
I think if I save it in a file the we can read the data as a Stream. I search how to save the FormatConvertedBitmap to a file but did not find any function for it. if you have any solution can u suggest :)